# Как обновить gcc на windows 10?

Tags: windows, gcc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обновить gcc на windows 10?

Сейчас версия - 4.9.2

Такой вопрос возник при создании драйвера mysql для Qt. Выходит ошибка версии gcc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]